# Forge services are really slow when upload larger IFS files

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I have a couple of IFC files which are around 80MB each .
I'm using the Forge API java client ( https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-java-client).

I tried using both US and EMEA services(Data Management and Model Derivative) but what I experience is to retrieve metadata and properties it takes a huge amount of time. Whereas I tested the same server calls (on EMEA) using postman and it took only 11 seconds.

Any advice on this matter ? Or does my Forge account type matters as Im on trail account. Or should I call the services directly instead via the provided java api client ??

Answer (score 1):

Many of the SDKs are auto-generated from Swagger specs, so it's possible that the Forge SDK for Java has some performance issue when retrieving the metadata. I would recommend reporting a potential bug in https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-java-client/issues, and for now, request the metadata from your Java application using a custom HTTP request (as explained [here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/5-ways-to-make-http-requests-in-java), for example).